# React function component with functions

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to create an instance of a function component like regular classes like c# and JAVA where you can call functions on the component? Something like:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-microservice-bp292?file=/src/App.js

It must be an instance so that the component can be used multiple places with its own instance and values. Not like a static class.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import MyFunc from "./MyFunc";

export default function App() {
  const addAlert = () => {
    MyFunc.addAlert("dasdsad");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addAlert}>Add alert</button>
      <MyFunc />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use hooks for that. You can store your business logic in hooks and reuse it in any components you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different concepts of ReactJS and the underlying DOM. It is not possible to get a ref on the functional component itself. At most you can use `forwardRef` to get a reference to the underlying DOM element. You can read more about that [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

With that in mind you could change your approach by uplifting the state to the parent e.g.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [alerts, addAlerts] = useState(["Alert1", "Alert2"]);

  const addAlert = () => {
    addAlerts(alerts.concat("dasdsad"));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addAlert}>Add alert</button>
      <MyFunc alerts={alerts}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyFunc.js

```
const MyFunc = props => {
 
  return (
    <>
      {props.alerts && props.alerts.map((alert, index) => (
        <div>{alert}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyFunc;
```

Comment: Thanks appreciated. That is how I do it as we speak.